# vector class has an inheritance hierarchy . Can anybody explain the same?

Tags: vector, stl

```
template<class _Ty,
    class _Alloc = allocator<_Ty> >
    class vector
        : public _Vector_alloc<_Vec_base_types<_Ty, _Alloc> >
```

Comment: Explain what, specifically?

Comment: I am new to STL programming. I want to know how vector_alloc and vector_base_types are used here. I am using visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

It probably inherits from another class that handles memory allocation. If that class has no data members, the `vector` can benefit from empty-base optimization, and `_Vector_alloc` will take no memory.

If `vector` would instead have a data like `_Vector_alloc allocator;`, that data member would always take one byte, even if it is empty, because C++ requires all data member to have a distinct address.

*Iterators:*

For `std::vector`, the iterator is basically a wrapper around a pointer, and most likely contains a pointer as single data member. It has additional data members, so as to satisfy all constraints defined in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator . (For the case of `std::vector::iterator`, `RandomAccessIterator`)

However the additional members iterators should have (for example `std::vector<T>::iterator::value_type = T`) are always accessed through `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type`. This allows raw pointers to be used as iterators as well, because `std::iterator_traits<T*>::value_type = T` is defined by the STL. So pointers are technically already iterators to contiguous memory.

Iterators of other containers are more complicated. For example in `std:: unordered_map::iterator` the items are grouped in different buckets. The iterators is a separate class, and not derived from the container. Because it is an inner class (defined in the namespace of the class), it has access to the container's private members, and is logically part of the container.

The iterator is not const-correct: `std::vector::iterator` always gives non-const access to the item it currently points to, even if one has only const access to the iterator. So each container class contains two iterator classes: `std::vector::iterator`  and `std::vector::const_iterator`. With const access to the container one can only get `const_iterator`s from it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the concept of iterators. How do they fit in here. Where do they come in inheritance hierarchy? As far as I know, they behave as pointers to elements of container. How are they able to point to elements of any container?